# Tensorflow: "not a valid checkpoint"

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to restore a recurrent neural network from a .cpkt file. My code to restore the network is:

```
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, n_steps, n_inputs])
    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.OutputProjectionWrapper(
        tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(num_units=n_neurons, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        output_size=n_outputs
    )
    outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    name = "rnnMonthly2"
    saver.restore(sess, os.getcwd() + "//RNNConfigs//" + name + "//" + name + ".cpkt")
    X_batch = priceArrayToRNNFormat(getPriceArray(symbol="IBM")[-30:0])
    y_val = sess.run(feed_dict={X: X_batch})
    print(y_val)
```

For reference, the text checkpoint file says that the path of the checkpoint files are as follows:

```
model_checkpoint_path: "/home/john/Python/StockProject//RNNConfigs//rnnMonthly2//rnnMonthly2.cpkt"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "/home/john/Python/StockProject//RNNConfigs//rnnMonthly2//rnnMonthly2.cpkt"
```

For this reason, I would figure that given the file path I fed into saver.restore the model should be restored properly. However, when I run the code I get the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/john/Python/StockProject/monthlyRnn1.py", line 151, in <module>
    saver.restore(sess, os.getcwd() + "//RNNConfigs//" + name + "//" + name + ".cpkt.index")
  File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1538, in restore
    + compat.as_text(save_path))
ValueError: The passed save_path is not a valid checkpoint: /home/john/Python/StockProject//RNNConfigs//rnnMonthly2//rnnMonthly2.cpkt.index
```

What is the cause of this error and what can I do to fix it? For reference, this is the code I used to train and save the network:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    mse_list = []
    init.run()
    for iteration in range(n_iterations):
        dataOrig = allStocksDict[list(allStocksDict.keys())[iteration]]
        X_batch, y_batch = priceArrayToRNNFormat(dataOrig)
        print(X_batch, y_batch)
        print(X_batch, y_batch)
        sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
        mse = loss.eval(feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
        print(iteration, "\tMSE", mse)
        mse_list.append(mse)
    print(mse_list)
    name = "rnnMonthly2"
    saver.save(sess, os.getcwd() + "//RNNConfigs//" + name + "//" + name + ".cpkt")
```